# Kotlin vararg array of array of any

Tags: arrays, generics, kotlin, variadic-functions

I have a method accepting a vararg of the form

```kotlin
fun arrayOfArrays(vararg aoa: Array<Any>) {
}
```

Now, I have trouble understanding how to call this method, e.g.

```kotlin
fun callArrayOfArrays() {
    arrayOfArrays(arrayOf(1), arrayOf(1))      // 0) works
    val a = arrayOf(1)
    arrayOfArrays(a, a)                        // 1) type mismatch: inferred type Array, but Array was expected
    val aoa = arrayOf(a)
    arrayOfArrays(aoa)                         // 2) type mismatch: inferred type Array<array>, but Array was expected
    arrayOfArrays(*aoa)                        // 3) type mismatch: inferred type Array<array>, but Array<out array> was expected
    arrayOfArrays(aoa.toList().toTypedArray()) // 4) works
}
```

**UPDATE:
After getting a heads-up by a colleague, we figured that adding types to arrayOf() fixes some of my problems, i.e. the following does work now:**

```
fun callArrayOfArrays() {
    arrayOfArrays(arrayOf(1), arrayOf(1))
    val a = arrayOf<Any>(1)
    arrayOfArrays(a, a)
    val aoa = arrayOf<Array<Any>>(a)
    arrayOfArrays(*aoa)
    arrayOfArrays(aoa.toList().toTypedArray())
    arrayOfArrays(*(aoa.toList().toTypedArray()))
}
```

I still believe that the former should be fine, too. And I do yearn for an understandable explanation for this behavior.

I appreciate that case 0 works, but I fail to understand all the other cases.

For case 1, I would expect that assigning the arrayOf(1) to a variable does not change the semantics, but here we are.

For case 2, I would expect that it works like I would expect the first case to work, just the "Any" being an Array here.

For case 3, I can see the difference, but I do not understand it, and certainly do not know how to ever make this work.

For case 4, I believe this is the vararg taking a single array. However, I cannot spread it either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this has to do with what `T` is inferred to be in the calls to `arrayOf<T>(...)`.

The way I understand it is the following:

In case 0, the param type expected by `arrayOfArrays()` is `Array<Any>`, and thus it makes the compiler infer `Array<Any>` as the type of the expression `arrayOf(1)`. The compiler then checks that 1 is an instance of `Any`, which is true (because `Int` is a subtype of `Any`), and therefore 1 is a valid parameter for `arrayOf<Any>()`.

In case 1, though, `arrayOf(1)` has no other type information than the parameter 1, which is an `Int`, and so the expression as a whole is inferred to have the type `Array<Int>`, which is not a subtype of `Array<Any>` (because of the invariance of the generic type parameter here). The error message is not that great, though, I have to admit.

Same goes for case 2, where the type of `aoa` is `Array<Array<Int>>` instead of `Array<Any>`. Again, the error message is not very helpful.

Case 3 is really the same as case 1, where each element in `aoa` is expected to be of type `Array<Any>` but is of type `Array<Int>`. It could work if `Array` was covariant in `T`, that is probably where the "expected `Array<out Any>`" comes from, but I really don't fully understand the error message here.

Case 4 is similar to case 0 in the sense that the compiler has more local type information (the type expected by `arrayOfArrays()`), and so it guides the way it will pick the `T` when interpreting the declaration of `toTypedArray()`.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time! This does make sense to me. In my actual code, I only had to insert a few type parameters and all errors were gone. I do not yet understand why vararg T implies Array<out T>, but I will get to that eventually, I hope ;-)

Comment: @Matthias I guess you have already given a look, but just in case you want to find out more about these `out` and `in` keywords, you can [read more about generics and variance in Kotlin here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/generics.html)